# java.lang.RuntimeException: Settings logger used after project was loaded

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

i am using play framework 2.6 and sbt latest version
I ran sbt -jvm-debug 9000
and received this following error.
not sure how to solve this.
(any suggestions is welcomed in order to improve question)

```
[Ecom OS] $ run

java.lang.RuntimeException: Settings logger used after project was loaded.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) Settings logger used after project was loaded.
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 6 May, 2022 2:49:17 PM
[Ecom OS] $ last compile:run
java.lang.RuntimeException: Settings logger used after project was loaded.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at sbt.LogManager$$anon$1$$anonfun$slog$1.apply(LogManager.scala:110)
    at sbt.LogManager$$anon$1$$anonfun$slog$1.apply(LogManager.scala:110)
[error] (compile:run) Settings logger used after project was loaded.
```